CString formatting from hexadecimal array causing segmentation fault on Raspberry Pi
Trying to convert a hexadecimal unsigned char array into a CString and printing:
unsigned char hexArray[] = { 0x1A, 0x2B, 0x3C, 0x4D, 0x5E, 0x6F };

CString strArray;
strArray.Format(_T("%02x-02x-02x-02x-02x-02x", 
                   hexArray[0], hexArray[1], hexArray[2], hexArray[3], hexArray[4], hexArray[5]); 
printf("strArray = %s\n", strArray.GetString());

This gives a segmentation fault. What is wrong?
